# returning users count more than expected

Tags: php, jquery, json, underscore.js

I am returning rows from a database table which I am serializing to json so as to display the results by making an ajax call.

When I view the results in my chrome console it looks correct but when I try to display it or do a count it returns way more than expected.

```
$id = $_POST['userId'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";    
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (!$result) {
    die("Database connection failed");
}
$results = array(); 
foreach($result as $row){
   $user_id = $row['id'];
   $user_username = $row['username'];
   $user_name = $row['name'];       
   $results[] = array('$id'=> $user_id, '$username' => $user_username,'$name' => $user_name);        
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

front-end

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'deleteUser.php',
                data: {userId: userId},
                success: function (data) {
                    container.Users = data;
                    console.log(container.Users.length);//returns a count of 773
                    console.log(container.Users);
                }
            });
```

However, the correct json does seem to be returned but when I try to render it in my page with an underscore template it returns 773 rows without displaying any values.

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
            <% _.each (container.Users, function(user) {%>
            <tr>
                <td><%= user.$id %></td>
                <td><%= user.$username %></td>
                <td><%= user.$name %></td>
                <td><input type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' name='delete' value='Delete' data-iddelete=$id id = <%= user.$id %>></td>               
            </tr>
            <% }); %>

        </table
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: _`//returns a count of 773`_ So with this comment you are getting 773 records but in console you don't see 773 records?

Comment: If you look in thr table, do you have a lot of null rows maybe?

Comment: So how many rows are there in the database table? Are you getting mixed up somehow due to loads of duplicate data?

Comment: i think `length` willgive you the string length (of the json string), not the amount of elements in the array

Comment: @Burki JS arrays also have a length property which does contain the number of elements.

Comment: @JonStirling that is correct, i edited my comment: i am unsure about the behaviour with a json string. but from the data in the question it seems plausible that length gives the string length. decoding the json and calling `length` on the resulting array would most likely give a different result

Comment: @Burki Yeah, you could be right. We need more info.

Comment: As mentioned below: the [screen capture of the console](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MdKzU.png) (present in first version of question) shows _very clearly_ that the json has already been parsed (by jQuery). OP has stated this appears fine. The problem here is with the underscore template, not with PHP, not with the Ajax call.

Comment: Have you tried using vanilla js loop instead of the underscorejs, to see if the implementation of _.each is causing that mess

Comment: Cool, will do that instead. It looks like the underscore.js loop is causing the problem

Comment: Try inserting a `console.log(user)` in the template loop, that will at least let you confirm whether the `user` object is correct for each iteration, and maybe if the problem is that `_.each()` does not work properly. Empty values sound like `undefined` properties on an object.

Comment: Thanks, I did, what it does is displays every char of the object, hence so many records.

Comment: Adding `dataType: "json"` solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `foreach` is something that looks a bit strange to me. It might not answer your question but I would like to suggest the following edit:

```
$results = array(); 
foreach($result as $row){
    $results[] = array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'username' => $row['user_username'],
        'name' => $row['name']
    );

    // Or if your query might return double results
    $results[$row['id']] = array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'username' => $row['user_username'],
        'name' => $row['name']
    );
}
```

The second option in the above example will set the user's id as array key. If the user id is rreturned multiple times, it will overwrite in the array.

#### Your template

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <% _.each (container.Users, function(user) {%>
    <tr>
        <td><%= user.id %></td>
        <td><%= user.username %></td>
        <td><%= user.name %></td>
        <td><input type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' name='delete' value='Delete' data-iddelete="<%= user.id %>"></td>
    </tr>
    <% }); %>
</table
```

#### Ajax call

Adding `dataType: "json"` below `data: ...` might solve some issues.

Comment: This is functionally the same so won't do anything to help the actual problem.

Comment: The `length` bits are properties, not functions and arrays in JS do have a length property.

Comment: Concerning the ajax call... as shown from the console screencap, the json string has already been parsed by jQuery, so yes it will totally return the length of the array.

Comment: Wow, absolutely right. Thanks. adding this `dataType: "json"` solved the problem